# colour outliers from box plot in scatter plot r

Tags: r, outliers, boxplot

I captured outliers of Days variable of a dataset usairnew in bout as given below:

```
> outlier.colors <- (days1 %in% bout)
> outlier.colors
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now I am trying to colour those outliers, (3 are there) in scatter plot.

```
> plot(usairnew$Days,main="Scatter plot for days",col=outlier.colors)
```

but I am getting only outliers in scatter plot now. How to get those as in red colour and all other points in black.

[image: outliers - scatter plot]

Comment: You're supplying colour as a logical, which is then being converted to 0 (none)/1 (black). See the section "Color Specification" in ?par, which gives three ways to specify colors; see what happens if you add 1 to your colours

Comment: May I know how can I give colours only to outliers? I am able to fetch them... If I do as plot(days1,pch=16,main="Scatter plot for days",col="blue"), all points are becoming blue including outliers...

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as below:

```
outlier.colors <- (days1 %in% bout)*1

outlier.colors <- outlier.colors+1

plot(days1,main="Scatter plot for days",col=outlier.colors)
```